# UITableViewCell - Changing All Cells to BackgroundView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I would like to add a UIButton to my TableViewController that will change all the cells in a UITable to the backgroundView from the contentView.

It would have the same functionality as setting self.myTableView.editing = YES to reveal the editingAccessoryView for all the cells.

Is this possible? If so, how can this be done? Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

The button toggles a flag (e.g. sets a BOOL property to YES if it is currently NO) and calls `[self.myTableView reloadData]`.

This causes `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to be called again for all the visible rows. And `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` *examines* that flag (the same BOOL property) to decide what to do about the background view.